# Custom Design Close /Minimize button on WPF Form?

Tags: wpf

Is there anyway I can create a Windows WPF form with custom design of the Close, Minimize, Maximize Button?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll require pretty much code but you might want to have a look at GlassWindow in FluidKit at CodePlex: http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/

The source code has a custom Window Style looking like this. I've used it once and it works good

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Yes you can](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx).